# Will changing my newsletter's from email address to another on the same domain affect deliverability?

Tags: email, bulk-email, newsletter

I have a fairly large newsletter that goes out daily. I setup the newsletter originally to send from xxx@example.com (an inbox I actively use); it has been sending from that email for almost two years and when I setup it up originally, I did not realize the amount of auto responders I'd get clogging up my inbox.

Recently, I modified my newsletter to send from xxx@example.com but reply-to yyy@example.com, an inbox that sends out canned responses. This cut down on the majority of auto responders but some are still getting through. As such, I'm thinking of setting both send and reply-to addresses to yyy@example.com. However, I'm afraid I may kill deliverability if I do this. Any thoughts? If the two emails are on the same domain, will it affect deliverability? If it will, are there any other options that I could employ?

Comment: Why do you think that you will *kill deliverability*? Why would *two emails are on the same domain* be a factor? Please let us into your train of thought on this??

Comment: @closetnoc I don't know. Is it possible for it to hurt deliverability -- that is the whole reason I'm asking.

Comment: I did not know if you had a working theory that we could address more specifically. But no. Neither of these are issues to be concerned about. You should be fine.

Comment: @closetnoc Thank you for the response. The only theory I could think of is people who specifically added my old email to their contacts. Other than that, it was a general inquiry. Thank you for quelling my fears, I took the dive!

Answer (score 2):

The reputation of the Email sender depends on "example.com" the domain and not for the email address "xxx@example.com".

Hence you can easily make this shift without any deliverability issues. As Its the Domain that matters.